# add values to javascript variable - object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add values here:

```
var selected_value = {
    addtypeid: addtypeid,
    isnew: isnew,
    geographicareaid: geographicareaid,
    catid: catid,
    catid2: catid2,
    manufacturerid: manufacturerid,
    modelid: modelid,
    yearofmanufacturing_from: yearofmanufacturing_from,
    yearofmanufacturing_to: yearofmanufacturing_to,
};
```

using this code:

```
var categories = [];

$("input[name='categoriesfilters[]']:checked").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var value = $(this).val();
    categories[categories.length] = {
        id: value
    };
});

$.each(categories, function (id, value) {
    //alert('id : ' + id + 'value:' + value);
    selected_value.id = value;
});
```

however, only the last checked checkbox is added in the following format:

```
id[id]  166
```

while i would like to have there all the checkboxes in the format:

```
166:166,
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Regards, John

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the problem?

Comment: You should probably have to change: `categories[categories.length] = { id: value };` to `categories[categories.length] = { 'id': id, 'value': value };`

Comment: and how i will add those values to my var selected_value? that is my main issue

Comment: First of all you must add `id: []` and `value: []` properties into your object 'selected_value' and then you can use `selected_value.id.push(value)` and `selected_value.value.push(value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='categoriesfilters[]']:checked").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var value = $(this).val();

    categories.push({
       id: id,
       value: value
    });
 });


$.each(categories, function (id, item) {
   //alert('id : ' + id + 'value:' + value);
   selected_value[item.id] = item.value;
});
```

Comment: i get error in this line: categories.push(obj); // obj is not defined

Comment: are you sure you define the object above i.e. var obj = {}; By the way, are you sure the error says obj is not defined? This is a valid JavaScript code even if you do not define the obj. The only error i can imagine in that line is - categories is not defined

Comment: you are right, sorry. however, now those values are not added in my selected_value...in the post in the console they are nowhere to be seen. any chance that we can solve this on chat?

Comment: if you provide a jsFiddle I'll try to sort it out for you

Comment: Can you check if the categories array has data?

Comment: console.log show this, if i check 2 checkboxes: [Object { 170="170"}, Object { 174="174"}]